# Opencv compilation in eclipse for android ndk

Tags: android, c++, eclipse, opencv, android-ndk

I'm developing an android HMI application for lane detection in eclipse on windows. The lane detection algorithm is in CPP file using opencv. I used JNI to integrate android app with the algorithm. But i'm not able to run the application due to following error :

OpenCV Error: Unspecified error (The function is not implemented. Rebuild the library with Windows, GTK+ 2.x or Carbon support. If you are on Ubuntu or Debian, install libgtk2.0-dev and pkg-config, then re-run cmake or configure script) in cvShowImage, file /hdd2/buildbot/slaves/slave_ardbeg1/50-SDK/opencv/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp, line 501

i have followed all the steps specified by http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/android_binary_package/android_binary_package_using_with_NDK.html

Request for suggestion where did i go wrong.

Comment: I think you should check `JavaCV`.

Comment: will javacv libraries support cpp files?